# React mui button input file not opening local machin file directory

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a button as an input field of file type, I have tried to wrap the input field with the button, and hide it. But, this is not working since nothing happens when I click on the button. I don't get the dialog to choose the files from the local machine. This is my component:

```
class MediaPlaceholder extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      file: null
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
    })
  }
  render() {
    const {classes} = this.props;
    return (
      <Paper className={classes.media}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="upload-file">
            <Button  onClick={event => this.handleChange(event)}>
              Add media...
              <input
                accept="image/*"
                className={classes.input}
                id="upload-file"
                type="file"
              />
            </Button>
          </label>
        </div>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}
```

I saw in few places that this is the suggested solution, so I am wondering why is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Material-UI docs/example https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#contained-buttons :

```
<input
    accept="image/*"
    className={classes.input}
    id="contained-button-file"
    multiple
    type="file"
  />
  <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
    <Button variant="contained" component="span" className={classes.button}>
      Upload
    </Button>
  </label>
```

So you could try :

```
class MediaPlaceholder extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      file: null
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
    })
  }
  render() {
    const {classes} = this.props;
    return (
      <Paper className={classes.media}>
        <div>
          <input
              accept="image/*"
              className={classes.input}
              id="upload-file"
              type="file"
            />
          <label htmlFor="upload-file">
            <Button  onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
              Add media...
            </Button>
          </label>
        </div>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}
```